# using definition of derivative

Tags: derivatives

$f(x)=x^3-6x^2+9x-5$ is given.
What is the value of $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{[f'(1+2h)+f'(3-3h)]}{2h}$$

I tried to use the definition of derivative,and here it seems like the expression will be equal to something like the **2nd** derivative of $f(x)$ but I'm confused with $2h$ and $-3h$.

Comment: The answer is given as -15.

Comment: you mean confuse*d* :)

Comment: Thanks :) It should be mathandgrammer.stackexchange :)

Comment: Do you know l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Yes but I use it when the limit results in 0/0 or inf/inf. Can we use it for this question?

Comment: Yes, if you plug everything in, you'll end up with something that results in $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Thank you all, all 4 answers and the comment of @Ataraxia helped me a lot to solve few similar questions in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $f'(1)=f'(3)=0$. Rewrite our limit as 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(1+2h)-f'(1)}{2h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\frac{f'(3-3h)-f'(3)}{-3h}.$$

Comment: I was looking for such an answer but I didnt see that f'(1)=f'(3)=0. I added **-f'(1)+f'(1)** [ and the same for f'(3) ] so they made the expression a bit complicated for me.Thank you

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$f'(x)=3x^2-12x+9$$
and notice that
$$f'(1)=f'(3)=0$$
Now by the definition of the derivative we have
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{[f'(1+2h)+f'(3-3h)]}{2h}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{f'(1+u)-f'(1)}{u}-\frac{3}{2}\lim_{v\to0}\frac{f'(3+v)-f'(3)}{v}\\
=f''(1)-\frac{3}{2}f''(3)=-15 $$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $f'(1+ 2 h) = 9 - 12 (1 + 2 h) + 3 (1 + 2 h)^2$
- $f'(3-3h) =9-12 (3-3 h)+3 (3-3 h)^2$
- $f'(1+2h) + f'(3-3h) = 8-12 (3-3 h)+3 (3-3 h)^2-12 (1+2 h)+3 (1+2 h)^2$

So, we have:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{[f'(1+2h)+f'(3-3h)]}{2h} = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{-30 h + 39 h^2}{2h} = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{-30  + 39 h}{2} = -15$$ 
Can you fill in the details?

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** the second derivative, since the points the first derivative is evaluated at are not the same points. That being said, you can just calculate the first derivative, plug in $1+2h, 3-3h$, and see what you get.

For reference, note that you'll get (after some simplification):
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{3h(13h-10)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-30h}{2h}=-15$$